# Write external storage permision denial but permission is granted

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm retrieving an image from the camera with this code:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
```

And I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/images/media from pid=29557, uid=10243 requires 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

But when I debug the code permision checker I get a 0 when I chek it like this:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); //0
```

I saw similar problems but with reading (which is working well with the same code and it asks for permissions the first time).